# how to increment property in an object with a method in that object javascript

Tags: javascript

How go I get the booked property to increase when the `makeBooking` method is called.  Not getting the desired result, what am I doing wrong learning JavaScript.

```js
var hotel = {
  name: "pacific",
  rooms: 40,
  bookings: 35,
  booked: 30,
  roomType: ['deluxe', 'double', 'suite'],
  pool: true,
  gym: true,
  checkAvailability: function() {
    return this.rooms - this.booked;
  },
  makeBooking: function() {
    var roomSpace = this.checkAvailability();
    var addBooking = this.booked;
    if (roomSpace > 0) {
      addBooking = addBooking++;
      console.log('room has been booked');
    } else {
      console.log('no room available');
    }
  }
};


console.log(hotel.checkAvailability());


var roomTypePush = hotel.roomType;
roomTypePush.push('rental');
console.log(roomTypePush);

console.log(hotel.booked);

console.log(hotel.makeBooking());

console.log(hotel.booked)
```

Comment: You can just do `this.booked++;` instead of that `addBooked` variable

Comment: Please use this.booked++. addbooking points to a new variable which just has the value of this.booked.

Comment: @ambes - how will addBooking +=1 work? Whats the difference?

Comment: this.booked++, when you asign a simple type to a variable it does not link back to the original property

Comment: replace "addBooking = addBooking++" with "this.booked++". you can remove the addBooking variable alltogether

Comment: this.booked++ works, thanks for the elaboration @Vatsal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.booked++, when you asign a simple type to a variable it does not link back to the original property

```js
var hotel = {
  name: "pacific",
  rooms: 40,
  bookings: 35,
  booked: 30,
  roomType: ['deluxe', 'double', 'suite'],
  pool: true,
  gym: true,
  checkAvailability: function() {
    return this.rooms - this.booked;
  },
  makeBooking: function() {
    var roomSpace = this.checkAvailability();
   
    if (roomSpace > 0) {
      this.booked++;
      console.log('room has been booked');
    } else {
      console.log('no room available');
    }
  }
};


console.log(hotel.checkAvailability());


var roomTypePush = hotel.roomType;
roomTypePush.push('rental');
console.log(roomTypePush);

console.log(hotel.booked);

console.log(hotel.makeBooking());

console.log(hotel.booked)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this snippet.

```
var hotel = {
  name: "pacific",
  rooms: 40,
  bookings: 35,
  booked: 30,
  roomType: ['deluxe', 'double', 'suite'],
  pool: true,
  gym: true,
  checkAvailability: function() {
    return this.rooms - this.booked;
  },
  makeBooking: function() {
    var roomSpace = this.checkAvailability();
    var addBooking = this.booked;

    if (roomSpace > 0) {

      addBooking = this.booked++
      console.log('room has been booked');
    } else {
      console.log('no room available');
    }
   }
};


console.log(hotel.checkAvailability());


var roomTypePush = hotel.roomType;
roomTypePush.push('rental');
console.log(roomTypePush);

console.log(hotel.booked);

console.log(hotel.makeBooking());

console.log(hotel.booked)
```

when you do addbooking =  this.booked and then increment addbooking it does not point to the original variable.

Hope this be of some help.

Happy Learning